# WPF how to exempt task bar when maximize window

Tags: wpf, windows

I've a wpf window and i applied style for window header and added some code to maximize window with out covering task bar when i click on maximize button and its working fine. But the problem is when i drag window towards top window maximizing fully by hiding task bar so any one help me to get out of this.

Thanks,
@nagaraju.

code for dragmove :

```
void OnTitleBarLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {                          
                Window window = this.TemplatedParent as Window;
                if (window != null)
                {
                    window.DragMove();
                }            
        }
```

maximize code:

```
void MaxButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window window = this.TemplatedParent as Window;
            if (window != null)
            {
                if (state=="MAX")
                {
                    window.Width = 1181;
                    window.Height = 670;
                    window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                    CenterWindowOnScreen();
                    state = "MIN";                    
                }
                else
                {
                    //maxButton.ImageDown = "/images/normalpress.png";
                    //maxButton.ImageNormal = "/images/normal.png";
                    //maxButton.ImageOver = "/images/normalhot.png";
                    state = "MAX";
                    window.Width = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
                    window.Height = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
                    window.Top = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Top;
                    window.Left = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Left;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid a lot of hassle and don't do this yourself - use the [shell integration library](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell).

Comment: Given that there seems to be no docs at all an example would be nice. On that page I see nothing about full-screen; it seems to be more about Windows 7 features and full-screen windows are a lot older than that.

Comment: @kent thanks for your response, can you tell me or provide any sample that how can i use this shell library in my view.

Comment: @nag: try reading the linked page: "A sample project using the library's functionality is provided as a reference with the source download for this release"

Comment: @kent those source download is not available.